# Xamarin Studio gives error on new project

Tags: frameworks, xamarin

Just installed `Xamarin Studio 5.8.2` (build 7). Already have `.NET Framework 4.5.1` installed (due to `VS2010` and `VS2013` installed). Also installed `gtk sharp 2.12.25`. Upon any newly created project, I get

```
Error while trying to load the project. Project does not support framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.
```

It is the latest version. I downloaded today, and got an update a few hours later for gtk sharp and XStudio.

Comment: What sort of project is this? VB.NET?

Comment: Currently MonoDevelop and Xamarin Studio do not support VB.NET projects that target .NET 4.5 - https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/32a3095891c74a82bc6df6c3c2c264aab0e0b0e7/main/src/addins/VBNetBinding/VBLanguageBinding.cs#L94

Comment: Alright, but it's automatically set to 4.5. I'm surprised at that. Regardless, I've changed to 3.5 and 4, and the new project won't compile. I just get bad image exception.

Comment: Not sure if there is a maintainer for the VB.NET addin in MonoDevelop. I reported a compiler bug for VB.NET. Not sure if this is the one you are seeing - https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=24461

Answer (score 2):

You can try editing the .vbproj or .csproj files to change the TargetFramework from 4.5 to 4.0

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28329/error-while-trying-to-load-empty-vb-net-project

Comment: I changed my TargetFramework from 4.5 to 4.0, and now I'm not getting that error, but instead I'm now getting this error:


Cannot open assembly '/[project path]/[project name]/bin/Debug/[project name].exe': No such file or directory.


I confirmed that there is no exe in that directory. There is an exe in a directory for a C# project I made sometime back. How do I get Xamarin to make the exe for a VB project?